# codeigniter not running in xampp 1.7.3(Cant load class)

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

it was well and fine when i was xampp 1.7.2.

When installed xampp 1.7.3  and run my site from localhost, it shows

```
load->database(); 
$this->load->helper(‘url’); $this->load->helper(‘html’);
function entry_insert()  { 
$data1 = $this->upload->data(); //echo $data[‘file_name’]; $data = array( 
‘user_id’=> $this->session->userdata(‘id’,TRUE),  /* insert the user id */ 
‘pic_name’=> $data1[‘file_name’],
‘comment’=>$this->input->post(‘comment’,TRUE) 
); 
$this->db->insert(‘picture’,$data);
} 
function getall()    { 
$this->db->select(’*’);
$this->db->limit(6); $this->db->from(‘picture’); 
$this->db->join(‘users’, ‘picture.user_id = users.id’); 
$this->db->order_by(“picture.id”, “desc”); $table = $this->db->get(); return 
$table; 
} 
function general(){ 
$data[‘base’] = $this->config->item(‘base_url’);
$data[‘css’] = $this->config->item(‘css’); 
$data[‘userfile’] = ‘File Upload’;
$data[‘comment’] = ‘YourComment’; 
$data[‘heading1’]  =‘News Heading’; 
$data[‘summery’] =‘summery’; 
$data[‘news1’]=‘News’; $data[‘id’]=‘id’; 
$data[‘fid’]=array(‘name’=>‘fid’); 
$data[‘fsummery’];
```

..............

like things.

I made apache’s AllowOveride from none to all. 
but does not work.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

any insight?

Comment: Is php working at all?
That output contains no error but unparsed php code, check that out.

Comment: It runs. i run the <?php phpinfo()?> in a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by enabling short tag in php.ini

Comment: if that works great, however you really should not use short tags in your code. as it can cause problems, and i believe is deprecated

Comment: @Eric it's not deprecated and it isn't a bad practice anymore. At least concerning '<?' and '?>', the ASP tags probably are deprecated.

Comment: short tags are deprecated in php 6